# How to write multiple entity classes that share functions in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, dry

I have multiple entities that have some sort of file attached to them. I have followed the cookbook entry on how to handle file uploads with doctrine ([here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)) but my question is this:

How can I do this for multiple entities without duplicating lots of code? Right now all of my entities share the functions related to getting the path, albeit with some modifications here and there, so they are not identical, but most of the code is. What is the cleanest way of doing this?

Here is an example of two entities, notice overlapping functionality:

Image:

```
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    $dir = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->getParentDir();

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir);
    }

    $slugger = new \Sam\TourBundle\Service\SlugService();

    $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->file->getClientOriginalName());
    $path = $slugger->slugize($pathinfo['filename']).'.'.$pathinfo['extension'];
    $this->path = $path;

    // If file already exists rename it
    if (file_exists($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
        $i = 1;
        while (file_exists($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
            $this->path = $i.'-'.$this->path;
            $i++;
        }
    }

}

/**
* @ORM\PostPersist()
* @ORM\PostUpdate()
*/
public function upload()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    $dir = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->getParentDir();
    $this->file->move($dir, $this->path);

    $thumb = new \Sam\TourBundle\Service\ThumbnailService();
    $thumb->makeThumbnail($this->getAbsolutePath());

    unset($this->file);
}

/**
* @ORM\PostRemove()
*/
public function removeUpload()
{
    $file = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    $thumb_file = $this->getThumbnailAbsolutePath();

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }

    if (file_exists($thumb_file)) {
        unlink($thumb_file);
    }
}

public function getParentDir()
{
    return $galerija = $this->getGalerija()->getSlug().'/';
    //return null === $galerija ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$galerija.$this->path;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->getParentDir().$this->path;
}

public function getThumbnailAbsolutePath()
{
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->getAbsolutePath());
    $thumbpath = $pathinfo['dirname'].'/'.$pathinfo['filename'].'_thumb.'.$pathinfo['extension'];
    return null === $this->path ? null : $thumbpath;
}

public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getParentDir().$this->path;
}

public function getThumbnailWebPath()
{
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->getAbsolutePath());
    $thumbpath = $pathinfo['filename'].'_thumb.'.$pathinfo['extension'];
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getParentDir().$thumbpath;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
    return realpath(__DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir());
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view
    return 'images';
}
```

Document:

```
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    $dir = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->getParentDir();

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir);
    }

    $slugger = new \Sam\TourBundle\Service\SlugService();

    $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->file->getClientOriginalName());
    $path = $slugger->slugize($pathinfo['filename']).'.'.$pathinfo['extension'];
    $this->path = $path;

    // If file already exists rename it
    if (file_exists($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
        $i = 1;
        while (file_exists($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
            $this->path = $i.'-'.$this->path;
            $i++;
        }
    }

}

/**
* @ORM\PostPersist()
* @ORM\PostUpdate()
*/
public function upload()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    $dir = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->getParentDir();
    $this->file->move($dir, $this->path);

    unset($this->file);
}

/**
* @ORM\PostRemove()
*/
public function removeUpload()
{
    $file = $this->getAbsolutePath();

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}

public function getParentDir()
{
    return $ponuda = $this->getPonuda()->getSlug().'/';
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->getParentDir().$this->path;
}

public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getParentDir().$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
    return realpath(__DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir());
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view
    return 'documents';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally create an upload service class with an method which you can pass the entities, you can inject this service wherever you need and have it written in only one place.
Generally is not a great idea to have this kind of logic in your entities I believe.

Inheritance in this case looks completely incorrect from my point of view since it's a way of adding behavior instead of a generalization, you could do it but I'd advice against it. Inheritance per se is way overused and not the cleanest way to work, and Doctrine's implementation of it is quite annoying to work with as well. Traits could do it, though I haven't had much experience with them yet in this kind of environment. 
I'd strongly advice using services the way Symfony was meant to be used.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, thanks! I'm not so sure about using traits though, how widespread is PHP 5.4 among hosting providers?

Comment: Yes, that's a concern. I'm not sure how popular it is, I don't usually work with servers I can't manage. If you're using third party servers then you should know beforehand which version of PHP or if they will provide all the servers and extensions you need for your application. Again, I still think a service is a better approach than traits. I'm also not sure how mature is PHPUnit on testing traits, and that'd be a concern for me.